# How does below method of array initialization differ in context to array bounds checking?

Tags: c, arrays, bounds

Why does `int arr[2]={10,20,30,40,50}`  leads to error?
Why can't this initialization escape error by Array Bound Checking?

```
int arr[2] ;
arr[0]=10, arr[1]=20, arr[3]=30, arr[4]=40;
```

Doesn't cause error in context to C language by array bound checking?

Comment: The keyword is "undefined behaviour". You should have read about it in your C book, if not re-read it or get  a better book. For details, so some basics research, there is a plethora of posts about this already.

Comment: @T.Akki what is the reason of abusing the contract between you and the compiler? You say 2 elements bu later assign the 30rth. What for? Better think how to avoid it in your programs.

Comment: A compiler is only required to inform you what cannot be compiled, not what cannot be run, although they do have various helpfulness.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 Isn't the 2nd example abusing the contract between me and the compiler ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no runtime array bounds check in C.  You are free to obliterate whatever is in memory.  The 1st example you show, is a compile-time structure, so the compiler know that you declared an array of size 2, and that the initialization has > 2 elements.

Comment: "You are free to obliterate whatever is in memory" - 1) NO! 2) That's undefined behaviour, all bets are off, what actually happens. It should even format the harddrive.

Comment: Thanks @OldProgrammer