# Is providing more initializers in an array initializer list than there are elements in the array a syntax error?

Tags: c, arrays

I was told this is true (in the pearson book How to Program), however when compiling inside the ide of NetBeans,

the following function code

```
int n[5] = {6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2};
```

does not result in a compile time error however does cause unexpected behavior further in the program. Accessing locations in the array that shouldn't exist also does not cause a syntax error.

```
printf("%d", n[7]);
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Not a syntax error, but worse: undefined behaviour...

Comment: A syntax error is clearly a violation of syntax rules, this is not such. Instead as @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ commented, it would cause *undefined behavior*.

Comment: It is a constraint violation and must be reported by the compiler. It isn't really a syntax error though. It is syntactically correct but semantically incorrect.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ — it isn't UB. It is defined to be incorrect.

Comment: We had this question dozens of times already, One just recently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46144353/how-does-below-method-of-array-intialization-differ-in-context-to-array-bounds-c Get a better C book and drop obscure youtube videos and blogs.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Accessing an array beyond bounds **is** UB.

Comment: @Olaf — the initialization prevents the code from compiling.  The out of bounds access at runtime is UB once you get the code compiling.  I was referring to the first problem not being UB.  The second problem is UB, but only once the first is fixed and only if the array isn't big enough.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: We don't know what coldspeed refers to. Benefit of doubt and so… Anyway, this is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46144353/how-does-below-method-of-array-intialization-differ-in-context-to-array-bounds-c some hours ago. Coincidence? … Nah …

Comment: Netbeans is an IDE, nota compiler. Which compiler do you use? Any compliant has to emit a diagnostic message. gcc for instance does - with default warning settings.

Comment: MSVC reports *error C2078: too many initializers* (not a "syntax" error).

Comment: It would be interesting to know which compiler you are using so we can publically shame it on the internet. It might be misconfigured to not compile for standard C.

Answer (score 4):

Yes this code is wrong:

```
int n[5] = {6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2};
```

Per **6.7.9 Initialization**, paragraph 2 of [the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **Constraints**
>
> No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not
> contained within the entity being initialized.

As noted in the comments, this is a constraint violation and a *semantic* error that must be reported by the compiler.  I'd say any compiler that fails to report this error is deficient.

Comment: I understand that it is wrong, however the pearson book how to program just told me that it was a syntax Error so thats what I was looking to check with.

Comment: It's not a syntax error, how can it be? The compiler knows that there are more elements ... blah blah blah, but *syntactically*, it's a valid expresion.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I quoted the C standard, which **clearly** and **specifically** states "No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized."  The C standard seems to be silent as to exactly what type of error it is, but how can you claim it's NOT a syntax error given that paragraph?

Comment: @AndrewHenle That is from $ **6.7.9 Initialization**, nothing to do with syntax rules. It can be an error, but I doubt it's a *syntax* error.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi OK, then *what* kind of rule is it?  As noted in another answer, GCC enforces the standard with an actual error.  I suspect GCC authors are quite familiar with applying the C standard to building an actual C compiler.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi The compiler considers syntactical errors and semantic errors in general as compiler errors.

Comment: @AdamGoodsell: Looks like you should get a better book then. Or you missinterpreted something.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow *compilation error* != *syntax error*, that's what I am trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a constraint violation (aka "error") in C. Calling it a "syntax error" would be incorrect though. There's nothing wrong with the syntax in your declaration.

The only exception from this rule is permission to let the trailing zero-terminator to "fall off" the end of the character array when the initializer is expressed by a string literal

```
char str[5] = "Hello";
```

The above is valid in C even though the terminating `\0` character does fit into the array. (The `\0` character is discarded when it does not fit.)

If your compiler issued a warning for your declaration, then by issuing a warning it formally complied with standard requirements. Compilers like GCC will issue an error in `-pedantic-errors` mode.

Comment: About `str` initialisation being valid. Could you tell me how it works? Is the array size automatically made `6` to accommodate the `\0`? I mean, otherwise the `\0` could be written to some other adjacent memory and cause problems. I did `char s[5]="hello";` and printed `sizeof(s)` - it was still `5`.

Comment: @J...S: No, in such cases the trailing `\0` is completely suppressed/ignored. The array keeps the declared size and nothing is written into the adjacent memory.

Comment: gcc emits a warning without extra options (it has to).

Comment: So the string probably won't stop where we want it to when printed out because of the missing `\0`. Thanks!

Comment: @J...S - It isn't even a string when it is not properly terminated. But you are allowed to have an array of `char` just as well as having an array of `int`. Just don't try `strlen` or anything similar.

Comment: @BoPersson It seems that in gcc and clang, the extra values are ignored for all types of array not just `char`. I tried `int arr[4]={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}` and printed `arr[5]`. It ignored the value in the initializer list and had garbage value.

Comment: @J...S: That's how it should be. That's what expected from a compiler that decides to support this declaration as an extension. Anything else (i.e. either extending an array with explicitly specified size, or writing into memory beyond the array boundary) would look rather weird in the realm of C language.